# Swap is super slow on Xubuntu

Tags: swap

Swap is somehow super slow on xubuntu. I have 8GB ram running vivid 15.04 Xubuntu. When ram usage reaches around 7+gb ... the hdd light goes crazy (actually, it just stays on) and stuffs get dumped into the swap partition (16GB).

Question: Why does the whole system go frozen when this happen?

My sysctl settings are:

- vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5
- vm.dirty_ratio = 20
- vm.swappiness = 20
- vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50

Comment: Have you tried a higher swapiness? Maybe 60? 100?  Are you using so much RAM in a single, or multiple applications?

Comment: Yes, I am using that much ram, that is why swap kicked in to begin with.
I've tried different level of swappiness, but not 100.  Let me try 100 and post an update.

Comment: I specifically meant, **"Do you believe that there is a single application using quite a lot of RAM, or do you have many small things using this much RAM?"**.

Comment: swap is always slower then RAM and you either need to reduce your RAM use of purchase more RAM.

Comment: @earthmeLon, there is two or three apps that run up say 900+mb each.  Chrome, Firefox, and Android Studio Projects sometimes running up 1.2+gb.

The rest are the system, xfce desktop etc.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, thanks for the insight, the satori!  Why didn't I think of that?

The strange thing is, the ram to swap partition seem to be slower than file copy itself.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking - ram to swap slower than file copy ? how did you measure that ?